# Efficient Algorithm - Comparing lists with Virtual Scrolling

Tags: java, algorithm, list, user-interface, testing

I need to test an application through UI where there are two panels. 
One being **available items** and the other is **selected items**
These panes can contain thousands of items

Each available item has a checkbox used to select it and then the add button will add it to the selected pane.

My problem is there is virtual scrolling implemented on the panels.
Meaning I can only ever access a maximum of 16 items at a time,
(I've tried scrolling down to the bottom - but still, css selectors only work for the items I can see on the screen)

My Question is what is the best way to test this in terms of **moving items from one panel to the next**?[image: Mock Up Version]

Possible approaches:
**1)**  Move available items over to the selected items list (16 at a time) and assert they 16 got moved correctly ?
**2)** Move items over one by one asserting as I go they moved ok 
**3)** Save all available items to a list then add them all over and compared the selected items to the saved list.

Could threading be an option?

Arquillian, Drone and Graphene are used so tests are done with page objects using Java

Comment: Is this a Java or a javascript question? That you specify css selectors makes me think the latter

Comment: I add mored details in the question description, its an Arquillian, Drone and Graphene  project running functional UI tests, Page object code is done in Java

Comment: Can you post screenshot of the application? It will help us to better understand the problem.

Comment: OP wants to test a web UI using Arquillian, a testing platform for the JVM. See this page about [Arquillian+Drone+Graphene](http://arquillian.org/guides/functional_testing_using_graphene/) for details. So the tests are coded using Java, and they load a web page with an instrumented browser runtime (WebDriver/Selenium) and make it perform actions & test outcome. But question is unclear. @Lee92, what do you want to test about this dual list?

Comment: @HuguesMoreau  Ive add a mock up version (image)as the real thing is production code and can't be realised, but I'm looking for the best way of testing that those items are moved a crossed correctly given that the virtual scrolling i can only access 16 items at a time when there could be thousands of items it the lists

Comment: (My primary intention was to clarify the context for others, after seeing earlier questions above) The mockup was not necessary, that part was quite clear already. The elements of your lists are not all materialized in the DOM, so you can't use WebDriver DOM-searching functions to verify the UI state, alright. What is unclear is what you want to test: the *rendering of a temporary UI state that might be subject to change* or the *underlying functionality*? Can you programmatically move items across the list, then validate the dialog, then *test the actual outcome* instead?

Comment: Verifying content of your lists by programmatically scrolling them will be very complicated, and very-dependent on your "DOM-materialization" logic (or the framework you use to do that). I would look for another way. For example with WebDriver you can execute javascript snippets, perhaps with that you could access the *internal model* and verify that?